# Are there non-parametric equivalents to analyse nested data?

Tags: nonparametric, nested-data

I want to compare patient experience (continuous DV; N = 60) for two different treatment modalities (face to face vs. phone; between-subjects variable, one measurement). The sessions were run by one of two psychotherapists, both of whom conducted treatment sessions in both formats. My understanding is that the data from patients of the same therapist are not independent from each other, e.g. because of therapist idiosyncrasies.

Therefore, my understanding is that data analysis should take into account that the data are nested.

My questions are:
(1) Are there non-parametric tests that allow to take the nested nature of the data into account?
(2) If not, would it be an acceptable alternative to check whether the DVs differ between the two therapists and, if they do not significantly differ, analyse the data without taking the nesting into account?